# Are there any secret badges on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, badges

Has anyone witnessed any undocumented badges during their time on Stack Overflow?

By "secret", I mean a badge which is:

- *At least* unrepresented on the [Badges page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges)
- *At most* an enigmatic award whose appearance is unexplained
- *Not* a tag badge (which are dynamically created)

Comment: If we told you, then it wouldn't be a secret.

Comment: If there are, blink—err, upvote—twice.

Comment: Not possible to upvote twice

Comment: Without the secret "Double Fisted" badge, anyway

Comment: I've got a SUPER AWESOME GREAT JOB badge that nobody else has.

Comment: One word: **hats.**

Comment: I have my own badge. You can get it by doing 007 things ...

Comment: @cVplZ But Christmas presents are secret and they don't violate the Be Nice policy!

Comment: @DavidG You've obviously never unpacked wool socks as a kid

Comment: There is a secret *Jon Skeet* badge, you get that when you surpass him in total points.

Comment: There are platinum badges. Those are left to be awarded.

Comment: If you have over 1000 answers and 100% of your answers to questions deal with the topic of unicorns you get the *I LOVE UNICORNS!!!!!!!* badge. Which is purple and goes to the left of gold badges. You also get the benefit of using Unicorn coins: giving abilities such as up-voting your own post and changing other peoples profile picture to pictures of unicorns.

Comment: First rule is you don't talk about secret badges. Second rule is you don't talk about secret badges.

Comment: Type 'xyzzy' in one comment on each of seven different SE sites, and it unlocks a special badge.

Comment: @DonBranson: Nothing happens.

Comment: @DonBranson missed out an x at the end. It has to be a palindrome. And no, you won't see that others have got the badge until you have got one yourself.

Comment: @Carl, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xyzzy_%28computing%29.

Comment: @DonBranson TIL about xyzzy. Thank you :)

Comment: @Carl - yw. ____

Answer (score 77, accepted):

I assume by "secret badge" you mean a badge awarded to a user that is not documented in the [Help Center's list of badges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges). We can run the [following query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/240693) to find awarded badges that are not tag badges and not in the documented list of badges:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Name FROM Badges
WHERE Name NOT IN (SELECT TagName FROM Tags) AND
      Name NOT IN ('Altruist','Benefactor','Curious','Inquisitive',...)
```

where the list of badge strings in the second `IN` list comes from running

```
$(".badge-table .badge").map(function() {
    return "\'" + this.text.replace(/\s+$/g, "").replace(/^\s+/g, "") + "\'";
}).get().join()
```

on the badge page.

This query returns an empty result, so we can therefore conclude that either

- No undocumented badges have been awarded, or
- Awarded undocumented badges do not appear in Data Explorer results (i.e., they are not public, or at least not included in the data dump)

Since you explicitly ask for "an enigmatic award whose appearance is unexplained", we can go beyond badges to Winter Bash hats, some of which *do* have secret award criteria (see [I have a Secret Hat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211707/i-have-a-secret-hat), [How Do I Get the Winterbash 2013 Secret Hats?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212799/how-do-i-get-the-winterbash-2013-secret-hats) and [Winter Bash 2013 Wrap-Up](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/01/winter-bash-2013-wrap-up/)).

Comment: Nice! Thanks for the links about hats, those are interesting.

Comment: yeahhhhh still on the top row baby

Comment: Or: -- The NSA has altered the query engine to not return those results.

Comment: That query needs updating...

Comment: This only works if the secret badges are kept in the same table as the ordinary, boring badges.

Answer (score 24):

[Jeff Atwood wrote in 2009](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/no-we-have-not-forgotten-about-the-hacker-badge/):

> I’m specifically referring to **the secret Stack Overflow hacker badge**. It does exist, though it has yet to be awarded. (There might even be some other secret badges out there.. who knows?)

Because implementation was estimated to take "more than our usual 6-8 weeks", it might ship soon.

Comment: Specifically, on *April 1st* 2009. ;)

Comment: @JustinPowell The Hacker badge is not entirely a April Fool's joke, though. Back in 2008, the blog post "[Stack Overflow Badge Feedback](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/07/stack-overflow-badge-feedbac/)" listed Hacker as one of the site's initial badges. (Though the last we've heard of it was in that April 2009 post, which doesn't sound too promising: "It's just taking a while to get around to implementing it...")

Comment: Obviously the way to earn the secret Hacker badge is to hack into the site and implement it yourself.

Comment: The Hacker badge actually existed for a couple of days (it had badgeid 29). It was known to be awarded to [Kevin](http://stackoverflow.com/users/40/kevin), who found some XSS hack that allowed him to reskin his profile page. Subsequently, I guess the Stack Overflow team decided that that probably wasn't something that should be rewarded with a badge, and it disappeared since.

Answer (score 19):

I would definitely consider [this a real-world badge when you reach 200k+ reputation](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/what-happens-when-you-reach-200k-reputation/), or at least `an enigmatic award whose appearance is unexplained`:

[image: Unicorn badge]

The next more similar thing is the [Winter Bash](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/12/winter-bash-2013-is-here/). While they are not *badges*, they behave very similar (awarded when reached X objective) and there are some secret ones.

Answer (score 7):

A secret badge probably doesn't make much sense. There are a couple of definitions of "secret" that I can think of.

- Badges that are documented but have a secret way of unlocking them (this would come with your experience with the website, and require community members to not disclose it to newbies. Fun, but not exactly within the spirit of SO.)
- Badges that are simply undocumented. See [Unihedron's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275623/are-there-any-secret-badges-on-so?cb=1#comment111907_275660) which tries to identify these. If they existed, a meta post would reveal the nature of their existence quickly.
- Badges that are given in secret and rely on a [Cassandra Truth](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/CassandraTruth).

If you can't show off your badges to other people, then what is the point? Sure, it might feel good for a second that you have a badge that nobody else has, but that feels awfully lonely.

Comment: You mean http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/194/informed ?

Comment: Of course secret only goes so far—until someone earns it. But I meant, a badge whose requirements for acquisition are not readily available (either via the Badges page or during the award process).

Comment: The Beta badge is an example of the first bullet. The exact criteria for earning the badge are not disclosed so that people don't just shoot for the bare minimum, similar to how the exact algorithm used for banning users isn't disclosed.